# How to drop a row in Pandas if a third letter in a column is W?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe of this kind:

| ID | Jan | Feb | Mar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20WAST | 2 | 2 | 5 |
| 20S22 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 20W1ST | 2 | 2 | 5 |
| 200122 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

And I want to drop all the rows where the third letter in the first column is a 'W' to give an output:

| ID | Jan | Feb | Mar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20S22 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 200122 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

It is a very large dataframe and I tried doing something like this:

```
df[df.ID[2] != 'W']
```

But this only selects the item in the second row. I could potentially iterate over the dataframe but wanted to see if there was a better option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there. Use:

```
df= df[df['ID'].str[2].ne('W')]
```

you might want to reset the index after this selection

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to find the 3rd character

```py
out = df[df['ID'].str.contains('^.{2}(?!W)')]
# or
out = df[df['ID'].str.match('.{2}(?!W)')]
# or
out = df[df['ID'].str.match('.{2}[^W]')]
```

NOTE: difference between `str.contains` and `str.match` is that  `str.match` match the string from beginning of the target.

```
$ print(out)

       ID  Jan  Feb  Mar
1   20S22    0    0    1
3  200122    0    0    1
```